# Fast images cropping (manually)

Tags: images, image-processing

Here is the case: 
I have a lot of photos. Each photo should be cropped. Photos aren't the 'same': different sizes, different angles, etc. So each photo should be cropped by me manually, by selecting a rectangle. Is there a software that allows to:

1. Open a folder with pictures.
2. Automatically open first of them.
3. Crop a picture by selecting a rectangle.
4. Save cropped image and automatically go to the next.

An ideal way is: left-click to select a rectangle + press [KEY] to save changes and automatically go to the next.

UPD: OS - Windows\Debian, price - $0-100.

Comment: Any OS/price preference?

Comment: Windows or Debian\Ubuntu, $0-100.

Comment: Please add that info inside your question, as comments get deleted, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use Irfanview. http://www.irfanview.com/

Your requisite 1 and 2 has not much sense. Of course it can open a folder with pictures, but does not open the first one if you do not click it.

But it has shortcuts on the keyboard to crop and save, and you can simply go to the next file using the keyboard.

You can also configure the program so you skip some confirmation dialog boxes, for example overriding the existing file. So it would be pretty fast.

1. Open the first image.
2. Draw a rectangle.
3. Ctrl + Y (crop)
4. Press S or Ctrl+S to either override the existing file or to save to a new location.
5. Go to next image. (Right arrow)

(Just configure the program to fit images to window so it is faster for you viewing the full image)

Please work on a copy of your photos. You probably want to keep them.

Comment: Sounds like something I need. Thanks.